# Open source audio pattern recognition (finger printing)

Tags: audio, pattern-recognition, audio-fingerprinting

Is there any open source audio fingerprinting solution that provides a "Shazam like" solution?

[Shazam](http://www.shazam.com/) uses the commercial solution from [Landmark digital](http://www.landmarkdigital.com) but I am looking for an alternative (even if inferior in accuracy and performance) open source solution.

Any one knows anything about such implementation or even of a published not implemented algorithm?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ok. different search keywords, all the results I looked for.

http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Audio_Fingerprint

Thanks for anyone viewing

Answer (score 25):

- [echoprint](https://github.com/spotify/echoprint-server) looks like a solid alternative to commercial libs.

for speech recognition:

- [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/)
- [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)

we only tested echoprint and so far so good.

I know the answer is a bit late but as this page pops up in google, we may as well improve it over time :)

edited as CMU is speech oriented

Comment: For speech recognition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_speech_recognition_software

Comment: echoprint url is broken

Comment: url updated. thank you @SarveshMishra

Answer (score 14):

There are a few Open Source audio recognition projects out there, although you can forget the quality/performances of commercial audio identification services such as Shazam, SoundHound, etc. It also depends on what kind of recognition you want to do (audio files fingerprinting/tagging, real-time identification, OTA (Over-The-Air) recognition, etc.)

**Open Surce**

- [AcoustID/MusicBrainz](https://acoustid.org/) Provides tools to perform audio fingerprinting and metadata association (fingerprinter and server). You can put up your own fingerprint/metadata server or use MusicBrainz's service. Good solution for audio file fingerprinting and recognition, not suitable for real-time high-performances applications (i.e. OTA). We have also tested it for audio stream monitoring (broadcast monitoring) but the results were quite poor.
- [Echoprint](http://echoprint.me/) Provides the same tools as AcoustID (fingerprinter and server+metadata) and can also be used for audio stream monitoring as it can recognize snippets taken from anywhere within the audio with decent accuracy (but i wouldn't use it for serious commercial applications). They also claim it is suitable for OTA applications but the performances are nowhere suitable for production uses.
- **Last.fm** Not fully open source, although they have open sourced the fingerprinting module. You have to query their identification and metadata provider services as they do not provide a full fledged solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a solution in .NET check [SoundFingerprinting](https://github.com/AddictedCS/soundfingerprinting) library.

It's open source and built on top of Content Fingerprinting Using Wavelets research paper.

The algorithm is different from Shazaam's, but the general idea is similar: extract most prominent coefficients from the spectrum, then use them to build the fingerprints for later retrieval.

Description of the algorithm can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206507/Duplicates-detector-via-audio-fingerprinting).

Comment: do you know how can we use SQL server as permanent storage?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for JAVA library then go for MusicG, I have used it in my one of past project and its working fine.
http://code.google.com/p/musicg/