# Can anyone suggest a library for audio pattern recognition?

Tags: search, audio, pattern-recognition

Description of my problem:

I have a sample audio file and need to find it in another audio file (for example, to find starting and ending time of recognition fragment in the audio file).  Is there any library for performing this task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open source audio pattern recognition (finger printing)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269167/open-source-audio-pattern-recognition-finger-printing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/). It is a Open Source Toolkit For Speech Recognition.

Description : CMUSphinx is a speaker-independent large vocabulary continuous speech recognizer released under BSD style license. It is also a collection of open source tools and resources that allows researchers and developers to build speech recognition systems.

2) [RWTH ASR](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/rwth-asr/) (short RASR) is an open source speech recognition toolkit.

Description : The toolkit includes state of the art speech recognition technology for the development of automatic speech recognition systems. It has been developed by the Human Language Technology and Pattern Recognition Group at RWTH Aachen University.

3) [Julius](http://julius.sourceforge.jp/en_index.php?q=index-en.html#feature) : "Julius" is a high-performance, two-pass large vocabulary continuous speech recognition (LVCSR) decoder software for speech-related researchers and developers.

May be google provide more results, but i think above three are more than sufficient.

Comment: All three of these seem to be geared toward "speech" pattern matching. Are there any that do general sounds like "clap" or "police siren" pattern matching?

Comment: i have the same problem @Connor