# Analyze voice patterns IOS

Tags: ios, audio, speech-recognition

I am looking for a way / library to analyze voice patterns. Say, there are 6 people in the room. I want to identify each one by voice.

Any hints are much appreciated.

Dmitry

Comment: Have you tried searching online first?

Comment: First, Google it. possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634366/can-anyone-suggest-a-library-for-audio-pattern-recognition

Comment: This may be a better fit for the sister SE site, Signal Processing. http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yeah, those voting down my question are not actually getting it. @bitmapdata.com I'm not looking to recognize words, I just need to recognize voice timbres and differentiate.

Comment: @Hooked thanks for pointing me to that site!

Comment: @runmad no, I didn't know search engines existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The task of taking a long contiguous audio recording and splitting it up in chunks in which only one speaker is speaking - without any prior knowledge about the voice characteristics of each speaker - is called "Speaker diarization". You can find links to research code on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_diarisation).
>
> If you have prior recordings of each voice, and would rather do classification, this is a slightly different problem (Speaker recognition or Speaker identification). Software tools for that are available [here](http://mistral.univ-avignon.fr/) (note that general purposes speech recognition packages like Sphinx or HTK are flexible enough to be coaxed into doing that).

Answered here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3119/library-to-differentiate-people-by-their-voice-timbre