# Sound Pattern Matching

Tags: audio, matching

I need an algorithm (a sample program code if possible) to **compare sound patterns** from two files(.wav or .mp3)..

I wish to build an application in c++ which will take two source files as input and compare them whether they are equal.

I searched the internet but did not get an algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean by patterns? if they are 100% equal?

Comment: I don't think you want to check for *exact equality*, because that would be trivial. You are searching for a certain degree of *similarity* between two audio files which a human listener would recognize as the same sound. This is a really complex problem.

Comment: If you want to know how Shazam works, here's a [paper](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf) written by their team.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open source audio pattern recognition (finger printing)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269167/open-source-audio-pattern-recognition-finger-printing)